# Cannot read property of undefined (form validation) - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've searched Google but can't find the answer...

I have an `md-select` that looks like this:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
     <label>Type</label>
     <md-select ng-model="f.type" placeholder="Type" select-clear>
           <md-option ng-repeat="f in ctrl.type" value="{{f}}">{{f}}</md-option>
     </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

`ctrl.type` looks like this in my `controller`:

```
this.type = ["type1","type2"];
```

and I am also sending the `md-select` value to an object array like this:

```
var data = {
    kind: $scope.f.type,
 };
```

and then I am doing an `http.post` that is sending the `data` object to an api.

Now here is my question. I would like it that when the `md-select` is empty, and the users sends the `data` object that instead of getting the error `Cannot read property 'type' of undefined` that simply the data is sent but it has a value of `null` instead of `undefined`, and then when the `md-select` is populated it simply sends the value to the api. How would I do that? Would I have to do form validation? Is there a simple way of doing this because I have about 10 of the `md-select`s that I have to send.

Thank you.

Comment: Based on the code snippets you have posted it looks like you are mixing "Controller as" syntax with $scope. I'm not an Angular expert, but is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a empty/dummy option above your md-option with something like

```
<option value='null'></option>
<option ng-repeat="f in type" value="{{f}}">{{f}}</option>
```

But I think, empty element is coming in the browswer because you are not initializing your `f.type`. If you properly initialize your `f.type`, you don't even get that empty element and its `undefined` value. You can initialize as shown below.

```
<select ng-model='f.type' ng-change='toggleSelection()' ng-init='f.type = type[0]'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ng-options instead of ng-repeat.

For example:

```
<md-select ng-model="f.type" 
    placeholder="Type" select-clear
    ng-options="f as f in ctrl.type">    
</md-select>
```